# Is there a way to generalise Action and Action<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, action, extension-methods

So I have an extension method that allows me to log something when an action is executed. The implementation is like so:

```
public static Action Log(this Action action, string log) {
    return (() => {
        Console.WriteLine(log);
        action();

    });
}
```

But I want to allow for the action to also be an `Action<T>`. Is there a way to generalise this, so that `log` gets logged, but it does not change the signature of the action?

Or do I need 2 methods, one for `Action` and one for `Action<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need separate methods, but you can implement one in terms of the other to reduce code duplication:

Given your existing `Log(Action action, string log)`, you can add:

```
public static Action<T> Log<T>(this Action<T> action, string log) {
    return t => Log(() => action(t), log);
}
```

Or the other way around:

```
public static Action<T> Log(this Action<T> action, string log) {
    return t => {
        Console.WriteLine(log);
        action(t);
    });
}

public static Action Log(this Action action, string log) {
    return () => Log<object>(t => action(), log);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need two methods, as `Action` and `Action<T>` are not compatible with each other in this scenario.

It would be useful if `Action` was actually `Action<void>` to enable this behaviour, but that is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, Swift allows doing that, as `Void` is a datatype in itself. I was wondering if C# allows this too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use type `Delegate` and provide the arguments for you action as `param object[]` like this:

```
public static Action Log(this Delegate action, string log, params object[] args)
{
    return () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log);
        action.DynamicInvoke(args);
    };
}
```

You can use this extension like that:

```
Action<int> testAction = i => Console.WriteLine($"Test: {i}");
testAction.Log("Logging", 42).Invoke();
```

This results in this output:

```
Logging
Test: 42
```

Comment: Oh, I got the impression that the OP wanted `Log<T>` to return `Action<T>` (meaning the parameters tot the action wouldn't be passed to `Log`) -- but the OP didn't specify that. You could be right with your interpretation.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I had in mind, I wanted to store the resulting `Action` and invoke it later. But this is nice +1

Comment: Upvote because this is an interesting solution, but it involves some kind of "dynamic pattern". Since we are in C#, that is a statically typed language, the @hvd solution is far a better one. It is also consistent with what you find in the .NET base frameworks and most libraries available out there.